# AnythingSlider width with page scrollbar glitch?

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I am using anythingslider with width set to 100% so that it fills the page, and it works fine except when the page uses a scrollbar, then the slider is 100% + width of scroll bar.
Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the width of the slider to 100%. Make its parent to 100% (also set a height), then set the `expand` option to `true` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/4321/)):

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/300x200.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Script

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // If true, the entire slider will expand to fit the parent element
    expand: true
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 var width = document.body.clientWidth; // this is the inner or viewport dimension that excludes scrollbars 
 $("#slider").width(width);
```